# RavenDB Unable to boot server on local machine

Tags: ravendb

i keep having the same problem for a few weeks now and i can't seem to figure out what it is.
I recently stared using RavenDB and it was working fine, but after a few days when i come home and want to boot the server on my local machine it just does not want to boot, it gives the following stack trace in the logs:

```
2019-03-05T18:58:43.0323063Z, 1, Operations, Server, Raven.Server.RavenServer, Failed to create a webhost to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS, EXCEPTION: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Raven.Server.RavenServer.RedirectsHttpTrafficToHttps() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.1\41010\src\Raven.Server\RavenServer.cs:line 312
```

Now i am not very familiar with networking but i have no clue why initially it works for a few days and then it just stops working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that there is something that is already using the port that RavenDB is trying to bind into.
Check things like `Get-NetTCPConnection` output or `netstat` to verify that